# NLP - Found input variables with inconsistent numbers samples

Tags: python, nlp

So I'm trying to train a model to read the greetings from the sample dataset collected from Tripadvisor and I've been getting the following error when I am trying to train the model sets.

Here's the link to the dataset - https://nextit-public.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rsics.html?fbclid=IwAR0CktLQtuPBaZNk03odCKdrjN3LjYl_ouuFBbWvyj-yQ-BvzJ0v_n9w9xo

Here's my code;

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# NLP Pkgs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

import os


# Main Stuff

st.title("Greetings NLP - Presence")
st.subheader("Created using Streamlit - Harshil Parikh ")



# Loading the data into streamlit
@st.cache
def load_data(nrows):
    #data = pd.read_csv('/Users/harshilparikh/Desktop/INT/data/selections.csv', nrows=nrows)
    dataset = st.cache(pd.read_csv)('/Users/harshilparikh/Desktop/INT/data/selections.csv')
    return dataset


data_load_state = st.text('Loading data...')
dataset = load_data(1000)
data_load_state.text('Data loaded.')

#Displaying all data first
if st.checkbox('Show Raw data'):
    st.subheader('Raw Data')
st.write(dataset)


# GREETING TAB

st.subheader('Greetings')
greet = st.sidebar.multiselect("Select Greeting", dataset['Greeting'].unique())

select = dataset[(dataset['Greeting'].isin(greet))]
# SEPARATING ONLY TWO COLUMNS FROM THE DATA 
greet_select = select[['Greeting','Selected']]
select_check= st.checkbox("Display records with greeting")
if select_check:
    st.write(greet_select)


#Text- Preprocessing  - Range from 0 to 6758 total feedback
nltk.download('stopwords')
corpus = []
for i in range(0, 6758):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', str(dataset['Selected'][i]))
review = review.lower()
review = review.split()
ps = PorterStemmer()
review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
review = ''.join(review)
corpus.append(review)


#BAG OF WORDS
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 6758)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

st.write(X)
st.write(y)
st.write(cv)


#Training sets (800 values)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
#X_train[0, 0:10] #First 10 rows of the first column of X_train.

# NLP - Naive Bayes algorithm 

classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm trying to learn simple NPL. Any helps will be appreciated.

Error I'm getting

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 6759]
> Traceback:
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
> exec(code, module.**dict**)
> File "/Users/harshilparikh/Desktop/INT/first.py", line 90, in 
> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 2127, in train_test_split
> arrays = indexable(*arrays)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 292, in indexable
> check_consistent_length(*result)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 255, in check_consistent_length
> raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"

Comment: I need help with this urgently!

Comment: where does the error occur?  Can you add the Error to your question?

Comment: is your code correctly indented? Like this you add only one review to the corpus?

Comment: It's correctly indented, It's not throwing any errors for indentation  - 
I want to add 6758 records of reviews and if the they have greeting message (1 or 0) and then get a model of it. 

Hope that clears up my question @chefhose Thank you once again for your response

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs when calling the function *train_test_split*, x and y need to be of the same length, which is not the case. I suspect that the problem arises at your for-loop. Instead of adding all the reviews to your corpus you only add the last after leaving the for-loop. Try this instead:

```
for i in range(0, 6758):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', str(dataset['Selected'][i]))
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    review = ''.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)
```

Comment: That throws another error for me - 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6758, 6759]

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/Users/harshilparikh/Desktop/INT/first.py", line 90, in <module>
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

Comment: I fixed it but now all it's showing is 1500 records of single '2', Any idea why?

Comment: first, try to understand and solve it on your own. Then, if you really need help and there isn't a similar answer on stackoverflow already, ask a new question, please.

Comment: I read everything, Can you please explain to me what we're storing in the variables X and y? I am not getting the confusion matrix. :/ I tried working on it.